# RewriteRule not obeyed

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

http://localhost/allsides/.htaccess

RewriteRule    (.*) index.php?$1 [L]

http://localhost/allsides/test

One or more chars after allsides/ are saved in $1

$_GET is $1.

test is not $_GET!

What is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `…?test` is requested, `$_GET`’s first element’s key will be `test` an has no value (equal to `…?test=`).

So either use `current(array_keys($_GET))` to get the key of the first element of `$_GET`  or use [`$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) to get the full query.

Comment: Hmmm... how to make $_GET be the one or more chars after allsides?

Comment: Change your rule to `index.php?path=$1` and look in `$_GET["path"]`.

Comment: print_r($_GET);

Array ( index.php => ) 


(.*)/?(.*)/?(.*)    index.php?controller=$1&action=$2&params=$3

print_r($_GET);

Array ( [controller] => index.php [action] => [params] => )


What is going on?

Comment: Try this: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?([^/]*)/?([^/]*)$ index.php?controller=$1&action=$2&params=$3 [L]